# htaccess en un SubDominio para vinculos amigables

Tags: .htaccess

Hola de plano no me queda, alguien me pueda ayudar con ello ?

Tengo mi proyecto que funciona ya bien local y remoto pero cuando quise implementar vinculo amigables utilizado el .htaccess ya nada funciono.

asi estoy **dominio.com** aquí esta la pagina web

Creo otro que se llama **programa.dominio.com** aqui esta el PHP, dentro esta este .htaccess que solo requiero que funcione dentro de **programa.dominio.com** y funcione dentro del directorio

mi arbol de directorios en el serivodor esta asi:

/Home

/public_html

/otros_directorios del servidor

/programa.dominio.com dentro estan los archivos php,js,css,etc

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
#Código que utiliza el WordPress para realizar URL amigables.
RewriteEngine On

#Pasar la URL a PHP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ enrutar.php/$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

#Redirección permanente de dominio www a sin www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.programa\.dominio\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://programa.dominio.com/$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301]

#Ocultar la extencio del archivo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1

#Restringir todo el acceso a carpetas
Options All -Indexes
```

Este debe madara todo a enrutar.php cuando yo le mande alguna solicitud como
programa.dominio.com/nuevo me manda a nuevo

Hay veces que requiero mandar programa.dominio.com/programa/perrito, y me deveria mandar al archivo programa.php?b=perrito

````
<?php #Establecer el control de las url.
#Para Vincualos amigables hay que establecer la ruta completa para archivos css, js img, etc.
$hostLargo = "https://$host/";

$url = sprintf("%s://%s%s",
        isset($http) && $http != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
        $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
       );

  $url = explode('/',$url); #explode — Divide un string en varios string
  #var_dump($url);

  if(!strcmp('programa.dominio.com', $url[2])){
    switch ( strtolower($url[3]) ){
      case 'nuevo':
        $ir_archivo = 'nuevo.php';
        break;
      case 'buscar':
        $ir_archivo = 'busqueda.php';
        break;
      case 'programa':
        $ir_archivo = 'programa.php?cr='.$url[4];
        break;
      default:
        echo "Error en URL LDefaul(30)";
        $ir_archivo = $url[3].".php";
    }
  }else{
    echo "Error en URL LElse(33)";
  }
  
  require_once ($ir_archivo);
}
?>```

Ya estado aquí deja de funcionar si yo pongo en mi url programa.dominio.com/buscar
Me manda a la pagina pero ya cuando le pongo un "/ este carácter o mas" todos se viene abajo ya nada me corre, no estoy seguro de que estoy haciendo mal o que revisar.

E agregado en el htaccess y funciona mejor pero sigo con el problema de que si supero mas de "/" todo se cae y no encuentro el por que

Si pongo programa.dominio.com/nuevo toda va bien

Si pongo programa.dominio.com/nuevo/ deja de funcionar 
´´´
RewriteBase /
´´´
````